# Call a handle_asynchronously method synchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm using Rails and delayed_job, and one of my methods is marked `handle_asynchronously` so that calling it automatically puts in on the DJ queue. Is there any way to override this declaration and call it synchronously instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but you should be able to call your method with `_without_delay` appended to its name because DJ uses `alias_method_chain` when `handle_asynchronously` is called.

So if you had `handle_asynchronously :do_work` you would call `do_work_without_delay`

Comment: Works for me! I'm going to submit a documentation pull request in hopes of making this an official feature. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I monkey patch in my environment files, as sometimes I am testing something that calls an asynchronous method:

```
  module Delayed::MessageSending::ClassMethods
    def handle_asynchronously(*opts)
      # no-op
    end
  end
```